# Adding a file to startup

Tags: java, startup

So I have a jar file and I would like to know how I can have it so when the PC start it jar runs if they select that option. I do not want to make the file into a .exe or use any 3rd party software to do this. I would also like if this worked on Windows, Linux, and Mac. Most solutions I've found were Windows only or used other software to do so.

Comment: Just set the OS to run the full java command at startup.

Comment: But wont the file have to be running to do so?

Comment: No. The java command is what starts the file. Read up on how java is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you solution will be OS dependent. The main thing is that you have to say `java -jar youjarfile.jar` in some way. That assumes that a JVM is installed and is accessible to the OS and it can run. In case of Windows there are different methods (registry, Startup), in case of Linux you can place it into the user's startup scripts (distro and shell dependent) or init.d sequence if you go system wide.

Comment: For Windows I think registry would be best. Though I have no idea for mac/linux. And is there a way to find the users's startup scripts?

Comment: It's distro dependent. For example there's `.bash_login`, but that assumes bash as a shell. You can also check `.bashrc`, `.login` or similar files. Distros can show a wide variety in this respect (this freedom is a burden at this time, but also a good thing in Linux). This is one reason why software companies rarely support linux, or they just support very specific versions of specific distros.

Comment: For Mac, I don't know form top of my head. You have to search.